# Parsing a Date String

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a date format as '12-FEB-2014' I need to convert it to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. I tried this:

```
xdmp:parse-dateTime("[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y0001]","12-FEB-2014")
```

But it throws an exception:

```
XDMP-PATTERNVALUEMISMATCH: Given value doesn't match with the specified pattern
for parsing dateTime string
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like with the month that you have you will have to make your own transform function. This code down below should give you a start. It will work off the example you gave us.

```
declare function local:month-name-to-int
  ( $stringIN as xs:string? )  as xs:string? {
   switch (fn:lower-case($stringIN))
   case "jan" return "01"
   case "feb" return "02"
   case "mar" return "03"
   case "apr" return "04"
   case "may" return "05"
   case "jun" return "06"
   case "jul" return "07"
   case "aug" return "08"
   case "sep" return "09"
   case "oct" return "10"
   case "nov" return "11"
   case "dec" return "12"
   default return fn:error(xs:QName("ERROR"), "unknown month")
 } ;

let $string := "12-FEb-2014"
let $stringTokened := fn:tokenize($string, "-")
return xs:date($stringTokened[3] || "-"||local:month-name-to-int($stringTokened[2]) || "-" || $stringTokened[1])
```

Comment: Now the function xdmp:parse-dateTime("[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y0001]","12-FEB-2014") seems gud to work with